# append data can't filter in json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have problem to filtering data with `jquery` and `json`

how do the best filtering data, but my code not find array in json ?

help find solved my problem. thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").keyup(function(){
    $("#result").html('');
    var searchField = $("#search").val();
    var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    $.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marshallt09/taruhan88/master/kotakabupaten.json", function(result){
      var x = result.listkotakabupaten;
      for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        if ( x[i].kotakab.search(expression) != 1 && x[i].kotakab.length != -1) {
          $("#result").append("<li>"+x[i].kotakab+"</li>");
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
}

li {
  padding: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  border:1px solid;box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="search">
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

this my jsfiddle code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrj1L80/110/)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question body, and to show some sample input JSON and the corresponding desired output.

Comment: depends on the JSON, which you haven't posted, nor have you posted what you're filtering for - so, the best answer is "a pineapple"

Comment: plz mention about searching parameter. Search exact word or matching result?

Answer (score 0):

`x[i].kotakab.search(expression) != 1` is inocrect. A search returns -1 if not found. Change it to:

```
x[i].kotakab.search(expression) !== -1
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vgrj1L80/124/