# How to dynamic delete table row with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

**How to dynamic delete row ?**

sorry i fail to embed `jsfiddle` to post

[my fiddle code here](https://jsfiddle.net/93wftwea/)

Comment: [As you have been told before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971609/append-data-cant-filter-in-json#comment74972964_43971609), your code must be **in** the question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *"sorry i fail to embed jsfiddle to post"* Sorry, but no. When you were asking your question, there were: 1. A big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area, 2. An entire toolbar of formatting aids, and 3. A **[?]** button giving formatting help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use jquery on click

`$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent('tr').remove();
});`

```js
$('.add').on('click', function() {
    $('tbody').append('<tr>' +
        '<td class="col-xs-1"><input type="text" class="no"></td>' +
        '<td class="col-xs-4"><input type="text" class="item"></td>' +
        '<td class="col-xs-5"><input type="text" class="description"></td>' +
        '<td class="col-xs-2">' +
        '<button class="btn">' +
        '<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>' +
        'Delete' +
        '</button>' +
        '</td>' +
        '</tr>');
});
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent('tr').remove();
});
```

```css
input {
    width: 100%;
}

.add {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 50px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn add">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> add
</button>
<table class="table">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-xs-1">No</th>
            <th class="col-xs-4">Item</th>
            <th class="col-xs-5">description</th>
            <th class="col-xs-2">Action</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-1">1</td>
            <td class="col-xs-4">Lipsum</td>
            <td class="col-xs-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea earum hic accusamus, reprehenderit recusandae, quisquam consequatur quasi eum cum, nam atque aperiam at? Veniam cupiditate, commodi numquam voluptates dicta nisi.</td>
            <td class="col-xs-2">
                <button class="btn">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```